Difference between adding value to variable by the content or by the select attribute
Basically I'm trying to write the node name of node stored in a variable to a file. My problem is that it works when I assign the variable's value by the select attribute and not when assigning by the content. I do need to get the latter working though, since I want that content to be conditional (which is not in the example below).
Can someone help me out on this? Thanks!
My environment is a proprietary software platform for variable data publishing using something (is engine the correct word?) from Altova to handle xslt. I'm using this engine in xslt 2.0 mode.
It all happens in this named template:
<xsl:template name="setValidatedEmail">
  <xsl:param name="docType"/>
  <xsl:variable name="break" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="contEm1" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="contEm2">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <validatedEmail>
    <xsl:result-document ...">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name-from-QName(node-name($contEm1))"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$break"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name-from-QName(node-name($contEm2))"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </validatedEmail>
</xsl:template>

which is called like this:
<xsl:template match="email">
  <xsl:call-template name="setValidatedEmail">
    <xsl:with-param name="docType">Stockbooks</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

local-name-from-QName(node-name($contEm1)) returns the string email (as expected), while local-name-from-QName(node-name($contEm2)) unexpectedly returns nothing.

Your code
<xsl:variable name="contEm2">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:variable>

creates a variable whose value is a new document node containing a copy of the context node or item ..
You can change that by using an as attribute
<xsl:variable name="contEm2" as="node()">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
</xsl:variable>

Or (without such an as attribute) you would need to select down into the tree e.g. $contEm2/* to select an element inside.
As for using the select attribute but doing conditional checks, XPath 2 and later have an if (conditional-expression) then sequence1 else sequence2 expression.

Thanks for explaining, Martin.
I have tested both your solutions,  and they work (as expected of course). So, I learned something new today!
I know about the if expression, but I can't use it because I'll have more than 2 options, and thus will need to use xsl:choose.

@Roebie, it is possible to use if (cond1) then exp1 else if (cond2) then exp2 else exp3 and of course more complicated/longer usages of this. But go with the as attribute and use xsl:sequence instead of xsl:copy-of if possible and all your xsl:choose usage will be fine and as efficient as select but perhaps more readable to yourself and other coders you don't go deep into XPath 2.

I've noticed that copy-of instead of sequence works too. Any difference or issues there?

@Roebie, yes, in the world of XSLT 2 and later I would suggest to mostly use xsl:sequence, not xsl:copy-of, particular with the as attribute on a variable, as only then you get the same effect as with a select attribute, namely that the variable is bound directly to a node or node sequence of the input tree that you process, and not to a copy you probably don't need. It doesn't make much of a difference for simple input and simple stylesheets but I have had people complain about memory issues and it turned out they used <xsl:variable><xsl:copy-of ...></xsl:variable> repeatedly.

Although none of all those intermediary copies created where actually needed, it was just a coding way intended to store (sequence of) nodes of the input in various variables and if you use as and xsl:sequence consequently you can save a lot of memory for larger inputs/XSLT processing.

Ah, I see. Well since my inputs tend to be pretty large, this is really valuable information. I'll check all of my xslt files on this. Thank you very much.
